# setinterval function is running infinitely

Tags: react-native

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  fire.database().ref().child(getpath())
    .once("value",
      (snapshot) => {
        let item = snapshot.val()
        console.log(item)
        if (item !== null) {
          let array = [];
          Object.
            keys(item)
            .forEach(i => array.push(item[i]));
          setCard1(array);
        }
        console.log(item, "item")
        if (item !== null) {

          itemlen = 7  //length of object I get from valid result
          //stop polling for results
          console.log(itemlen, "should clear")
        }
        else {
          console.log("polling")
        }
      })
}, 1000)
console.log("comingout")
if (itemlen !== 0) {
  console.log("goingIn")
  clearInterval(interval);
}
}, [prefVar]);
```

expected clearinterval to stop the setinterval function but it is running continuosly and not stopping
itemlen is getting non zero values.Is there a better way of implementing this ?
I want stop useEffect once I get valid value from db.My code inside the for setinterval selects a random path and retrieve that path only problem is that sometimes the path is empty,thus using setInterval

Comment: This line `itemlen = 7` is illegal. You are mutating a closure variable, which is *unsupported*, and this fact is all over the official docs. Use a state or reducer hook, and update it via the supported mechanism.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is well covered in the official documentation both for [class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and for [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two state items, one which keeps the interval and the other which stores `itemlen`, and would use another `useEffect` to listen on changes to `itemlen`, and when it is not 0, the interval should clear. Also, I would check if there is another interval running before you start another one.

```
const [itemlen, setItemlen] = useState(0);
const [pollingInterval, setPollingInterval] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    if (pollingInterval === null) {
        setPollingInterval(setInterval(() => {
            fire.database().ref().child(getpath())
                .once("value",
                    (snapshot) => {
                        let item = snapshot.val()
                        console.log(item)
                        if (item !== null) {
                            let array = [];
                            Object.
                            keys(item)
                                .forEach(i => array.push(item[i]));
                            setCard1(array);
                        }
                        console.log(item, "item")
                        if (item !== null) {
                            setItemlen(7);
                            console.log("should clear")
                        } else {
                            console.log("polling")
                        }
                    })
        }, 1000));
    }
}, [prefVar]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (itemlen !== 0 && pollingInterval !== null) {
        clearInterval(pollingInterval);
        setPollingInterval(null);
    }
}, [itemlen])
```